# Values replacing each other using UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, userdefaults

I have an app where I time myself and see how long it takes me to complete a bunch of questions. I have the time transferred to another VC and displayed in a label. I have it being stored by pressing a button but when i have a new variable(time) it replaces it. How do i store an Array of values and that can be displayed in a label?

Button to save the value:

```
@IBAction func saveScore(_ sender: Any) {
    scoreLabel.text = label.text
    UserDefaults.standard.set(scoreLabel.text, forKey: "score")
}
```

The code that permanently holds the data:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if let x = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "score") as? String {
        scoreLabel.text = x
    }
}
```

My scoreLabel displays all my scores and label shows the time you just got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following extentions on `UserDefaults` to store an array of times:

```
extension UserDefaults {
    var times: [String] {
        get {
            if let times = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "times") as? [String] {
                return times
            } else {
                return []
            }
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "times")
        }
    }
}
```

While you don't need to extend `UserDefaults`, using extension can simplify a bit working with persisted values and it makes the code cleaner.

Then at the point where you show the data, use the following line to access the array:

```
let arrayOfTimes = UserDefaults.standard.times
scoreLabel.text = "\(arrayOfTimes)" // or any other formatting you'd like
```

And instead of setting the times to persist a new score, just add the new score to the array, e.g.:

```
// This will not only add the scoreLabel.text to the array, but also persists it
UserDefaults.standard.times.append(scoreLabel.text)
```

Comment: Thanks Milan for the help it is very appreciated! How ever when i finish the game it displays "Label" instead of what the label said for example 23.5 seconds, eveything else is fine except that

Comment: that's not the problem of the UserDefaults.. most probably it is the problem of when you set the text of the label (and when you save the data to the UserDefaults). go over your code and try to save the data to the UserDefaults as soon as they are available, and refresh the label from the UserDefaults as soon as possible, when the label is presented. In the end, you dont even have to pass it between viewControllers, just add the values when you get to the end, and in the viewController with the label use the data from UserDefaults

Comment: Ok thanks, i will let you know how i go thanks for everything!

Comment: i needed to add UserDefaults.standard.times.append(down.text) to the saveScore button. As well as delete everything in viewDidAppear and add                                                 if let x = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "times") as? String {
            
           resultLabel.text = x
            
            
        }

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 4,**

To **save an array to User Defaults** you would do:

```
 let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

 let array = [25, 50]

 defaults.set(array, forKey: "Scores")
```

And **to access the array from User Defaults:**

```
 let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

 let retrievedArray = defaults.array(forKey: "Scores") as? [Int] ?? []
```

And if you were to display a score of your array in a label then, you would just do:

```
 scoreLabel.text = String(describing: retrievedArray[0])
```

> If you are using integers for your scoring system, I would suggest you
>   storing your scores as `Int` in User Defaults.

If you prefer using `Strings` though, please note that you can use the User Defaults' `stringArray(forKey:)` method directly, instead of the `array(forKey:)` method, and therefore, in that case, you wouldn't need to type cast your array:

```
let someStringArray = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "ArrayOfStrings")
```

*Note: To answer your question, I will consider that you are using Int scores, but feel free to use whichever you prefer.*

If you want to store your array **to the same key** in User Defaults **every time you get a new score**, you could do it easily like this:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

// Your new score:

let newScore = 75

// Get your current scores list from User Defaults:

var currentArray = defaults.array(forKey: "Scores") as? [Int] ?? []

// Append your new score to the current array:              

let updatedArray = currentArray.append(newScore)

// And save your updated array to User Defaults:

defaults.set(updatedArray, forKey: "Scores")

// In this example, your User Defaults now contains the updated array [25, 50, 75]
```

And that's it :).

Please note that there is no need to use an extension for that..

**UPDATE:** Also, if you want to add something inside your `viewDidAppear` method, don't forget to add `super.viewDidAppear(animated)`. The same goes for `viewDidLoad`, etc.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621423-viewdidappear) states:

> You can override this method to perform additional tasks associated
>   with presenting the view. If you override this method, you must call
>   super at some point in your implementation.

So you would have:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if let retrievedArray = defaults.array(forKey: "Scores") as? [Int] {

        print(retrievedArray)

        // You can access your scores array safely here
    }
}
```

Comment: I am unsure on where i should put this code. Which codes should i have for my save score button and for my userDefaults code in the viewDidAppear. I have put the code in where i think it goes but it isn't working at the moment. By the way i am using strings but should i be using Integers. Thanks so far!

Comment: If your score represents an integer in your app, then you would better save it as an Int indeed, it would make more sense. Of course you can still show your score in a label like I showed your in my answer, using String(describing:).

Comment: Well, you should place this code inside your @IBAction (save score), because you want to save your new score to User Defaults whenever the user taps on the save score button. :)

Comment: You're welcome! Just let me know if you have any other questions :).

Comment: Thanks Alex for all your help!